# ArcGIS Pro Ribbon and Button for Task?

Tags: arcgis-pro, tasks

If seen, that the [Tasks](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/tasks/whatistask.htm) is a good way to configure workflows for customers.

Is there a way to put a button to a group of a tab on the ribbon that starts a previously built task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [customize the ribbon](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/get-started/set-the-display-language.htm#ESRI_SECTION1_06CBA272961A4731B0F5E5A55785DF35) to add a given button to a either a NEW group or an EXISTING group. So from the **BACKSTAGE** > **Options** > **Customize the Ribbon** select *All Commands* from the *Choose Commands From*. You could add the *Import and Open Task* button. Your user would have to navigate to the .esritask file on disk and open it.

I dont see a way to point a button to directly open a task. If this is what you want to do I suspect you'll need to build an [Pro SDK add-in](https://github.com/Esri/arcgis-pro-sdk/wiki/ProGuide-Build-Your-First-Add-in) that embeds the esritask file and launches it. You'd then either distribute and have your users one time install the add-in, or pre-install it for them.

Or your 3rd option is to [create a template package](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/get-started/create-a-project-template.htm) (aptx). Your users would open that to get started and in the Catalog window, find and launch the appropriate task from the **Task** heading